# Python package name duplication

Tags: python, python-packaging

Suppose there is a package named `pkg_1` in PyPI. Can packages with names `pkg__1`, `pkg.1` or `pkg-1` be uploaded to PyPI?
[Here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) mentioned:

> name is the distribution name of your package. This can be any name as
> long as it only contains letters, numbers, `.`, `_` , and `-`.

But [Here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0503/) mentioned:

> Below the root URL is another URL for each individual project
> contained within a repository. The format of this URL is `/<project>/`
> where the `<project>` is replaced by the normalized name for that
> project, so a project named “HolyGrail” would have a URL like
> `/holygrail/`.

And by the normalized name, it means:

> The name should be lowercased with all runs of the characters `.`, `-`, or `_` replaced with a single `-` character.

So I guess a package named `a_.-b` is considered the same as `a-b`. Am I right?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by knowing this information?

Comment: Building a PyPI like repository.

Comment: pkg_1 and pkg-1 often amount to the same (one becomes the import name, the other is the pypi name). But depending on how similar you want to make your repo like pypi, you can set your own rules. Just be aware that you can't import `pkg-1` since that is a syntax error (hence the equivalency with pkg_1), and `pkg.1` would be a subpacka / submodule upon import: `import pkg.1`; which is also then a ayntax error, since `1` is not a valid identifier for a module. So `pkg.1` would also need to be renamed for importing.

Comment: Coincidentally being discussed right now: https://discuss.python.org/t/change-in-pypi-upload-behavior-intentional-accidental-pebkac/27707 -- I recommend using this function: https://packaging.pypa.io/en/stable/utils.html#packaging.utils.canonicalize_name

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the [*`packaging.utils.canonicalize_name()`*](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/stable/utils.html#packaging.utils.canonicalize_name) utility function from the [3rd party *packaging* library](https://pypi.org/project/packaging/) which is the library used by *pip* itself for this kind of work.

```py
from packaging.utils import canonicalize_name

names = [
    'pkg-1',
    'pkg__1',
    'pkg.1',
    'Pkg_-.1',
]

for name in names:
     print(f"{name=}: {canonicalize_name(name)}")
```

```
name='pkg-1': pkg-1
name='pkg__1': pkg-1
name='pkg.1': pkg-1
name='Pkg_-.1': pkg-1
```